# Azure Application Gateway API Management probe cannot connect to back end

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

I hope somebody can help to understand what I am doing wrong here because I am totally confused and lost.

I am trying to build an API Management in internal mode, and have in front of it a application gateway.

Following Microsoft Documentation I build the following resource:

- API Management
- Application Gateway
- Virtual network
- In the virtual network I set 2 subnets(application gateway and API Management)
- 2 Network Security groups one for each resources

As per the documentation and general advice I found online. I created a Keyvault and generated a certificate. In the Subject I set this CN:

```
api.test.com
```

I assigned a Managed identity to this KeyVault.

After this step I created a API Management Service. and the only api inside is a

`/configurations`

Once this was done. In the Newtork Tab I set the Api management to the internal mode and selected my virtual network and the subnet I designed for this service. So far everything went smooth. When the update completed I set the custom domain in the api management.

In the Tab `Custom Domain` I added a new domain, in the hostname I set the same CN I set in the KeyVault

`api.test.com`

and selected the KeyVault from which it has to fetch the right cert.

Everything is done here.

I created the Application gateway in the designed virtual network and subnet.

the first thing I set the backend pool to the gateway url of the API Management

`api.test.com`

I set a HTTP settings over protocol HTTPS port 443 as follow

[image]

Still in the application Gateway I set the Listeners on port 443 and selected my certificate from the KeyVault

In the Rules I configured the listeners and the back end targets to target the backend pool.

At this point, when I test the Probe:

[image]

I get the following error

```
Cannot connect to backend server. Check whether any NSG/UDR/Firewall is blocking access to the server. Check if application is running on correct port.
```

I checked both my security groups which are set as follow

this is the msg for the apim

[image]

and this for the application gateway

[image]

Can please anyone help understand what I am doing wrong here? Because I have no clue anyomore what could be the issue.

And please, if you need anymore info don't hesitate to let me know. And if is easy, I can post here my terraform script to deploy this infra.

Answer (score 0):

You said: *the first thing I set the backend pool to the gateway url of the API Management "api.test.com"*

That url is inaccessible and points to a public IP (which I guess should be the app gateway IP)

The backend pool should be the private SLB IP address of the api management service. the listener should be listening to the host name so when it receives a request with that host name, it forwards it to the api management service through its private IP and a host header holding the same listener host name as a value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for you advice and help. I Tried your advice and indeed it works, but partially. If I set your advice. I am able to troubleshot (blade on the side) the connection and I can hit my APIM private ip from the application gateway, but the probe is still `unhealthy`. This time the probe error is due to the CN mismatch. I changed the cert in my KV, but I am not able to update the listener cert. it throws an error that the cert is already used

Comment: read this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/renew-certificates

"Any change to Application Gateway will force a check against Key Vault to see if any new versions of certificates are available. This includes, but is not limited to, changes to Frontend IP Configurations, Listeners, Rules, Backend Pools, Resource Tags, and more. If an updated certificate is found, the new certificate will immediately be presented."

Comment: Also, in your scenario the cert should be updated in three locations, apim custom domains, app gateway listener and app gateway backend http settings

Comment: thank you so much for your time and patience. I read that documentation and had the cert updated in all the 3 point but still the same issue. Could it be that it needs time to refresh? or do you know by any chance if there is a way to check which cert is actually used in the app gateway listener?

Comment: Mismatch means that the cert on the backend http settings is different from the one under apim custom domains but I can't tell which one exactly,  try to compare through azure portal. How did you updated it at apim?

Comment: One suggestion to force apim to get the new cert if you are referencing the write one is to perform apply network configuration.

Comment: When you reference a new cert at apim, make sure you click save not just reference it.

Comment: I tried everything. forced the virtual network configuration as well. In the api I went to 'custom Domains' clicked on add. In the hostname I set 'api.test.com' and in the path the KeyVault with the cert, clicked on update and save.

Comment: Maybe I spotted the issue. Was checking my API Management Custom domains in the overview page. and my Gateway URL is settee `demo-testing-new.azure-api.net` shouldn't my certificate match this url instead of a `api.test.com`

Comment: Do you have a custom domain for the gateway endpoint? I would suggest a support ticket so the support team can check your configurations. Please upvote if I helped cornering your issue.

Comment: Or update with screenshot from your apim custom domains blade